# Dimmable pool color changing LED lights

Tags: electrical, lighting, led, dimmer-switch, pool

For whatever reason, color changing lights for pools are not dimmable (at least Pentair and Jandy brands - e.g. Microbrite Color) - the manual official states as such and warns about damage.

Only the white light version is dimmable. A pool builder said it's because there is a "motherboard" in the light.

Is there some way to accomplish this?  Perhaps a smart neutral density filter that sits in front of the light (couldn't find such a thing), or some other bulb (but maybe this is an inherent limitation of color changing LED bulbs?)

Comment: Even the regular plain LEDs don't get get along well with dimmers.  You usually have to check and match LEDs to certain types of dimmers for them to work right.

Comment: Yes you can dim  3 color LED’s the one we have in our MRI area is fully dimmable at any color but I doubt you want to spend thousands of dollars for the controller.

Comment: "motherboards" have "kids" that attach, this is just a controller board. It's possible to dim most colors if the app supports it. HSV/color wheel sliders make that process a lot easier than using RGB sliders or a color patch picker to do the same. Keep in mind that RGB-only lights can't easily do orange/brown or adjustable temp white light at anything close to full brightness. If your control system allows picking thousands of custom colors the light physically supports dimming, but your interface might not.

Answer (score 0):

### Color changing *is dimming*

Color changing involves 3 colors - red, green and blue.  It involves dimming each as an independent channel.

So for instance a bright amber might be 100,50,0.    That's 100% red, 50% green, 0 blue.

Well if we want to dim that, we change it to 30,15,0. Now red is at 30% and green is at 15%.  The red:green:blue ratio is kept the same, so it is the same hue and saturation, just not as bright.

### You can't stack dimming methods.

Dimming methods are basically incompatible with each other.  Even the same method will not stack twice.

You must choose one dimming method.

Better color-changing systems allow that fineness of control and synchronization (or independence) of many lights.

Comment: Not all color changing involves any dimming. There are some very basic color-changing lights that just cycle the R/G/B elements on or off in all possible combinations (red, green, blue, yellow, purple, teal, whiteish, off) with no finer level modulation. My hot tub has such a light.

Comment: I have analog/non-addressable common-anode RGB LED strip with 4 wires: [R,G,B,5v]. I can make colors by PWM'n the color channels (10bit). I dim colors by PWM'n the 5v channel at a much higher frequency and lower resolution (4bit). This scheme works well for a large (but not complete) range of values. It doesn't work with addressable LEDs (eg. ws2812b) that integrate a 3-chan 8bit PWM driver on each LED. You can use HSV to create dimmable colors on pixels, but at a reduced gamut and color accuracy will need calibration (compensation) which further reduces gamut. Still, it can be done...

Comment: @dandavis yes, in multi-LED strips, you are better off using PWM as a dimming method.  It's also possible to dim LEDs via current control, but that's best done on a single series string of emitters to assure equal current in all emitters - those LED strips are wired series-parallel which would expose variances in manufacturing.